# How to upgrade a firebase cloud function code to version 1.0 or higher

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I was trying to Push Notification on real time database change using firebase cloud functions , I searched the web to learn how to do it then I found a code on how to do it , I tried to upload the code to the firebase server but I got an error , I searched the web to see what's wrong where I found that there's a new version of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions , so can any one show me how to update the code in order to upload it to firebase server successfully ?

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.helloWorld = functions.database.ref('notification/{id}').onWrite(evt => {
    const payload = {
        notification:{
            title : 'Test',
            body : 'first notification',
            badge : '1',
            sound : 'default'
        }
    };

    return admin.database().ref('wlmsnotification').once('value').then(allToken => {
        if(allToken.val()){
            console.log('token available');
            const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,payload);
        }else{
            console.log('No token available');
        }
    });
});
```

The error : npm err! code elifecycle npm err! errno 1 npm err! functions@ lint: `eslint .` npm err! exit status 1 npm err! npm err! failed at the functions@ lint script. npm err! this is probably not a problem with npm. there is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Please follow the documentation to learn about the differences between versions.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: @DougStevenson , thank you Doug , I have already saw the documentation and I tried to edit my code by removing the ' functions.config().firebase ' and replacing the ' evt ' with ' change, context ' but I still got the same error , so am I doing something wrong ? or there's something else rather than upgrading to the new version ?